# When Clover's flushPolicy and flushInterval are set, what is impact on memory consumption

Tags: clover

I was googling it, but didn't find anything related to this, so asking here as I feel others might be interested too.

What is the impact on memory consumption when `flushPolicy` is set to `interval` or `threaded` together with some value of `flushInterval`? If shorter interval is used, will there be lower demand on memory as coverage collected so far will be offloaded to disk?

Little polling for real world usage:

1. Do you use these policies in practice?
2. What intervals do you use, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is practically no difference in memory consumption for different flush policies. Simply speaking (*), Clover works this way that it allocates one huge long[] array and keeps it in memory permanently. Flushing dumps array content to a file on a hard drive - array is not deallocated or shrinked.

*(*) There are three different coverage recorders for global coverage (https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Coverage+Recorders) and five different per-test recording strategies available (https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Clover+Performance+Tuning)*

Are *flushPolicy=interval* or *flushPolicy=threaded* useful? Yes, they are useful in case when you do not terminate JVM. Clover's default flush policy writes global coverage data only on JVM shutdown hook; which means you would get no coverage data until JVM is shut down. This is a scenario when, let's say your Tomcat server is running permanently and you're re-deploying an application and re-running tests.

What flush intervals can be used? From my experience, flush operation is very fast. Quick calculation: project having ~1MLOC may have ~1M methods+statements+braches which is ~4MB recording file, so on a 500MB/s SSD drive you can have ~100 flushes per second.

I've seen *flushInterval* values between 500ms and 5000ms. I suggest using lower values. Why? Because the Clover's reporting goal (clover2:clover) will pause for a 2*flushInterval until it starts report generation - in order to ensure that at least one flush operation has occurred. So having unreasonably high values of flushInterval will slow your builds.

Comment: I have quite specific setup where I gather coverage into clover.db on several virtual machines and then merge them on another machine. Having read your answer, looks to me that turning on interval flush policy will give me no performance benefit as you hold the recorded data in memory all the time anyways (is that correct?). Also in my case, recorded file is 90MB for which writing it to hard drive would unacceptably increase io operations.

Comment: "... that turning on interval flush policy will give me no performance benefit as you hold the recorded data in memory all the time anyway" - yes it's correct

Comment: "... in my case, recorded file is 90MB". Wow this is huge. How large your project is?